# how to execute a javascript or render html on after_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

or perhaps a work around?

Basically, my goal is, once the action has been completed, on my ApplicationController after_filter method, I want to modify/show something on the template with a javascript call that gets sent to the user's browser.

I'm okay with other solutions, need not be using the after_filter if there is no way you can do that in after_filter.

So a scenarion would be, after the controller action/all actions/methods have been processed, I'd do this:

```
document.getElementById("#errors").innerHTML = "Some error".
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you render something in a controller's action?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render something for all actions then put this in your layouts/application.html.erb file:

```
<%= javascript_tag "document.getElementById('#errors').innerHTML = '#{@error_message}'" unless @error_message.blank? %>
```

Then in ApplicationContoller:

```
def after_filter
    @error_message = "Some error"
end
```